# How to programmatically create symlinks in ddev?

Tags: ddev

A site (no composer, else I'd do it there) has a few symlinks inside the container that are required for it to work.
How do I tell ddev to create those symlinks on `ddev start`?

I'm sure it's right before my eyes, but I don't find it. Google gives me nothing, maybe the answer is too obvious? Do a `ln -s` on first run?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First,  I would probably create the symlink in my repo and check it into git. This would have problems on Windows (but symlinks in general are risky on Windows).

You'll want to use *relative* symlinks so that the relative path can be followed either inside the container or on the host.

So, use a post-start hook with exec (to do it inside the web container) if you have to:

```
hooks:
  post-start:
  - exec: ln -sf ../vendor/bin/behat behat
```

Or (especially if you're not on Windows) you could also do it on the host with either a pre-start or post-start hook:

```
hooks:
  pre-start:
  - exec-host: ln -sf ../vendor/bin/behat behat
```

Beware that the default directory for `exec` in the web container is not necessarily the project root, it may be the docroot (as it is with Drupal).

Comment: @Urs I edited to give full examples of what I was saying.

Comment: You say symlinks are problematic on windows. But they are inside the docker container, arent they? Although, we DID have issues with that site with ddev on windows, but I‘d never have thought it was beacause of the symlinks?

Comment: PS actually I used `exec: ln -sfn` (with the no-dereference flag) sounded like a fitting option for repeated use. In the WEB container.

Comment: Ah I guess the "problematic" part only refers to the hook in the host, right?

Comment: More on symlinks and windows is at https://ddev.readthedocs.io/en/stable/users/developer-tools/#windows-os-and-ddev-composer - and it matters to most people because they want their repo to look the same both sides (host and in container). Might not matter to you...